# How to change JVM settings of applications created by Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, jvm-arguments

When creating a desktop application from netbeans the default memory allocation on the JVM settings of the application are set quite low. This can cause OutOfMemoryExceptions in the application.

Is there a way to change the default JVM memory settings for the distribution build of a desktop application?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have created distribution build you can edit the "appName.conf" file of your application directly - where "appName" is the name of your application.

For Mac: show package contents and Contents/Resources/appName/etc/
For windows: /appName/etc/

The JVM startup options are listed under

```
default_options="--branding appName -J-Xms24m -J-Xmx64m"
```

The Xmx setting is the one to change.